# Getting a datagridview to refresh on timer

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to get my datagridview to refresh on a timer but unable to figure it out

I have done a lot of googling and a youtube videos and cant find the fix.

```
private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FillDataGridView();
        }
        private void FillDataGridView()
        {
            DataSet objDs = new DataSet();
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con2"].ConnectionString);
            MySqlDataAdapter myCommand;
            string select = "select * from CadCall";
            myCommand = new MySqlDataAdapter(select, con);
            myCommand.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            con.Open();
            myCommand.Fill(objDs);
            dataGridView2.DataSource = objDs;
            dataGridView2.Update();
            dataGridView2.Refresh();

        }
```

In the end I want the datagridview to refresh when the timer hits 0 (every 100 miliseconds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might regret such a short refresh interval. Make it 10 seconds, and don't forget to close/dispose your connection afterwards or your program will soon crash. The update and refresh invocations are unnecessary

A dataset is a collection of datatables, and a datagridview is intended to show the contents of only one table. A dataset hence cannot be a DataSource for a datagridview without the DataMember property being set, and I'm not really sure what your table name would be so I recommend alternatively that you make the DataSource one of the tables in the dataset, or use a datatable instead of a dataset:

```
DataTable objDT = new DataTable();
datagridview2.DataSource = objDT;

OR

DataSet objDs = new DataSet();
datagridview2.DataSource = objDS.Tables[0];
```

Oh and make sure you actually enabled the timer; they're enabled=false by default